# php read list from website into array

Tags: php, arrays, file-get-contents

I have a list of products codes that i wish to read into an array using php.

the list is to be fetched from a website and has over 700 items looks something like this:

```
4310ABC
4590DEF
8950GHK
```

What i want to do is put every code into a php array like so:

```
php_array ( [0] => 4310ABC 
            [1] => 4590DEF 
            [2] => 8950GHK)
```

This is what i have:

```
$php_array = file_get_contents('http://anysite.net/product_codes.php');
print_r (explode("\n",$php_array));
```

But my result is :

```
Array ( [0] => 4310ABC
               4590DEF
               8950GHK)
```

I have tried explode, preg_split('/[\n\r]+/', $php_array); but nothing seems to do the trick. Can anyone give me some pointers? thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you get back from your `file_get_contents()` call? Are you sure that it's using `\n` as a separator, and not `<br>`, for example?

Comment: print the contents of `$php_array` before you explode and examine it.

Comment: when i print the file_get_contents string is the list of items found on that website

Comment: @user1294097 Yes, but what do the codes look like in the php file? How exactly are they separated? Please show us sample of the codes in the file, directly from the file.

Comment: its no good looking in the browser at the output, the items could be in `<p></p>` for example. right click, view source

Comment: so looking at the source of the original php file where the codes come from each line is separated by a <br>

Comment: so you need to explode on `'<br>'` not `"\n"`

Comment: Thank you!!!! i been trying for a while without success. How do i choose your answer as the actual answer?

Comment: looks like @Dany beat me to it accept it instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lines are separated by a br, so use this instead:

```
$php_array = file_get_contents('http://anysite.net/product_codes.php');
print_r (explode("<br>",$php_array));
```

Don't forget to change the br to however it's spelled within the document you are fetching, for example it's often spelled like this:

```
<br />
```

Which is the most correct way to write it.

Comment: might want to trim the string or replace `" "` with `""` to get rid of any whitespace as well

Answer (score 0):

It would depend how your php file is echoing out the three values, so I am not sure how it is interpreting line breaks.  Try echoing out the values with no line breaks, but separated by some other character like '*' or something, and then explode them along that and see if that works.